# Using mkdirp folder creation issue in windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In my meteor application trying create folder and file in C:/Program Files/. But Program Files write permission has blocked by my admin. how to solve this through coding?

```
var pathname1 = "C:/Program Files/test/";
    var path1 = pathname1 + filename;
    if (!fs.existsSync(pathname1)) {
        var mkdirp = Npm.require('mkdirp');
        mkdirp(pathname1, function(err) {
            if (err && zpractice.global.System_settings.server_error_log)
                console.error(err);
        });
    }

    if (fileExists(path1)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(path1);
    }
    fs.writeFile(path1, fileData, function(err) {console.error(err);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run your scripts in admin mode.

Start `cmd` with right click `CMD.exe` and select "Run As...".

Or you can use [runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command:

`runas /user: localmachinename \administrator cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your path 
"C:\Program Files\test\";
And it's better to choose a path without spaces.

Comment: No, requirement is to create folder inside program files only and spaces is not problem i have tried with spaces, it's worked in different location..

Comment: I meant to use backslashes  "C:\\Program Files\\test\\"